# Choosing professional Monitor

Tags: gaming, monitors

Can't decide between these 3 monitors:

```
BenQ PD3220U
LG 32UL950
Dell UP3216Q
```

All 3 of them seem to have pretty similar characteristics and price which makes it really hard to choose.

All 3 are **4k60**, all come with **HDR-10** (though **LG** comes with **HDR-600**), all come with **10-bit** panel (I'm not sure though cause among these 3 only **BenQ** seems to come with ***"True"*** **10-bit** panel with **LG** and **Dell** having **8-bit+FRC**)

Could you please provide some arguments for any of these monitors ? Thank you

**UPD:** I'm planning to use a monitor mostly for working with graphics-design and for gaming

Comment: Can you clarify about graphic design? Because for some thing you don't need 10bit colour.

Comment: It is more like drawing digital art stuff, will I be able to distinguish the difference between 8-bit and 10-bit ?

Comment: I can't say, but IMO you do not need 10bits monitor. Of course if you create 16bits (per colour) images will be good to have.

Comment: Ok and what about HDR ? Is HDR-10 will be ok for me or do I need HDR-600 from LG ?

Comment: HDR-10 is established standard. But AFAIK it's mostly for movies, not sure if games will support it.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, Many games released in the last few years support HDR. But beware that a monitor *supporting* HDR does not mean you will see a noticeable difference. The monitor has to be capable of truly representing the 10-bit brightness levels with a strong backlight and accurate colour reproduction. Many "HDR" monitors just accept the signal and have underwhelming performance. This also applies to working with 10-bit images in photoshop. A low-end 10-bit monitor may not accurately represent the image and be no better than a high quality 8-bit monitor.

Comment: @Romen So what monitor would you recommend?

Comment: It appears that the LG monitor from your list has the highest colour gamut, which means the most capable of accurately representing high bit-depth colour. The BenQ actualy comes in at a close 2nd but it is not as bright, so HDR video/games will not be as impressive. All three of the monitors you've listed wouldn't be considered a "low-end 10-bit monitor", more on the mid to high end.

Comment: @Madi7, Also keep in mind that graphics you create on a high-end monitor don't look the same on cheaper 6-bit+FRC or 8-bit monitors that aim for sRGB colour. If you are printing your work, then you should absolutely go for the most colour accurate monitor possible. If you are creating work for digital/web use, then you should focus on making your graphics look best on 8-bit sRGB displays until HDR displays become ubiquitous. That means a 10-bit HDR display is overkill for web/computer graphics unless you are specifically making HDR content.